# Binding in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a div which displays the text. And below it have a textarea which can edit the text of the div.On typing the text of textarea the div text changes.I don't want this to happen.The problem is both div and text area is in ng-reapeat.Otherwise I would have used different scope for both.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div>
      {{item.text}} // this is the text that is changing when typing in text area
    </div>
    <div>

      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" ng-model="item.text" required>{{item.text}}
       </textarea>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the link to my issue
http://codepen.io/ankitappuria27/pen/pyVzaj

Comment: If you don't want that to happen, then bind the test area to a different variable. For example creating an additional `item.editedText` that initially contains the same value as `item.text`.

Comment: as JBNizet said you can do [this](http://codepen.io/singhakash/pen/ONZooO)

Comment: @JBNizet I don't want addition object to create as data is coming from database. As per your solution I need to modify data coming from database

Comment: The fact that the object is coming from database is irrelevant. Your Angular controller can add any attribute it wants to the objects it gets from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to change the text in your `div`, just use a **one time binding** like:

```
{{::item.text}}
```

**Note:** Any change you make inside your `textarea` will ofcourse still affect your models `text` value. The changes just won't be visible in your `div`.

**Example:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaxGOp

**Documentation:**

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding

Comment: @Ankita: It's a well hidden feature ;) Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your JS file you may add element in json for displaying header text just like below:

```
  app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.newitem = '';
  $scope.list = [
    {
      "order":1,
      "header":"Black", // header text
      "text":"Black"
    },
    {
      "order":2,
      "header":"Blue", // header text
      "text":"Blue"
    }
  ];

});
```

and your html for binding should be as below

```
    <div>
      {{item.header}}
    </div>
    <div>

      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" ng-model="item.text" required>{{item.text}}
       </textarea>

    </div>
```

Comment: I don't want extra field to get added as data is coming from database. I need to then modify json before displaying to user

Comment: I don't think it will gonna work that way as angular scope work through two way binding and when an element is bound to scope field it will be mirrored with value.